# Replacing the content of the stylesheet in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try change contents of stylesheet by htaccess, i have to use using HTTP_USER_AGENT and detect that current url is homepage (without any other in url, domain only).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^css/main.min.css$ css/homepage.min.css [L,R=301]
```

it's doesn't work. Is also problematic when i try change line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` with     `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact` -> example.com/contact does not load the home page stylesheet.
Without problem when i try redirect page to outside eg https://google.pl

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.pl [R=301,L]
```

Any idea how fix this problem?

Comment: _“and detect that current url is homepage”_ - but it _isn’t_, the “current URL” from the point of view of the rewrite engine is `css/main.min.css`

Comment: @CBore, thanks for reply. Then how to construct condition/any idea to fix problem?

Comment: You can not fix your problem at this level - HTTP is a stateless protocol, the server at this point has no idea, that the file was requested “from” your home page, and not a different page. (You could at most check the referrer, but that is highly unreliable.)